# wrong redirect in firefox with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

There is website with two different pages with photos:
`site.com/photo1.php` and `site.com/photo2.php`; both pages are redirected by htaccess in Search Engine Friendly URLs, so `site.com/photo.php?date=180322&name=event` transforms to `site.com/photo/180322/event/`

there are two snippets from htaccess, but the first one **doesn't work in firefox**. In chrome works good

```
# photo1.php - redirect (1st - NOT workable in FF)
RewriteRule ^photo1/([0-9]{6})/([a-z]+)/?$ /photo1.php?date=$1&name=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([0-9]{6})&name=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^photo1.php$ /photo1/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

# photo2.php - redirect (2st - workable in FF)
RewriteRule ^photo2/([0-9]{6})/([a-z]+)/?$ /photo2.php?date=$1&name=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([0-9]{6})&name=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^photo2.php$ /photo2/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

snippets are identical, but firefox at the 1st variant redirects to `site.com/photo1/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/.php/`

How should I solve this problem with FF?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I had to switch off Cashing in Preferences-Network. Now redirecting works as I wanted.